# Sweetalerts in laravel, always showing the alerts twice

Tags: laravel, sweetalert

So, I have the [uxweb/sweet-alert](https://github.com/uxweb/sweet-alert) package for Laravel and I've got a page that is loading an alert.

I'm running into a trouble whereby whenever I browse to the next page after loading the alert, it will load it again.

Is there any way around this or a way I can diagnose the problem?

TicketController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;

use DB;
use Alert;
use App\Tickets;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TicketController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $tickets = DB::table('tickets')->get();

        Alert::success('Tickets retrieved!');

        return view('frontend.tickets')->with('tickets', $tickets);
    }
}
```

My route file

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('tickets', 'TicketController@Index');
});
```

My master layout

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sweetalert.css">
</head>
```

and

```
<script src="js/sweetalert.js"></script>

@include('sweet::alert')

@include ('alertcancel')
```

Comment: Can u show us your code example?

Comment: Edited to include code

Comment: looks like you are alerting inside your index method via Alert package and then inside the script again calling alert

Comment: According to the [git](https://github.com/uxweb/sweet-alert) page @include('sweet::alert') should be put after your JS file

Comment: Can confirm when i take it out, it still happens also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a session problem. remove the `sweet_alert` key from the session so that it flashes only one time.

```
        @include('sweet::alert')

        <?php Session::forget('sweet_alert'); ?> <-- insert this
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Taken out and its still  happening.

Comment: Is this happening on all routes or on specific one?

Comment: Any page that i browse to that has the sweet alert included in the master layout afterwards yes.

Comment: Have you initiated sweetalert in your script? because in your example you've called alert in your method and when it redirects it opens the alert for you but when you click ok to close the alert, again pop up pops up?

Comment: There is no button to close the alert. The alert is popping up just fine, it disappears, then when i browse to the next page, it pops up again.

Comment: Can you confirm me that you are not initializing alert in your layout file or script. because it's the place which triggers on your every page load

Comment: I loaded all the things that i have mentioned into my master layout.Outside of that, there is no mention of sweet alerts in my application except for in that ticket controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120377/discussion-between-zayn-ali-and-james-mcconnon).

Comment: After following Zayn's advice in edited answer, worked perfectly!